# How to Detect if time stamp is over a certain time ago

Tags: php

I have the timestamp formatted in the regular way like this:

2012-02-23 20:34:55

I need to detect the following thing.

```
if(Timestamp >= 1 month ago) {

}

if(Timestamp >= 5 minutes ago) {

}
```

How would you detect that type of thing from a timestamp variable in PHP?

By the `>=` I mean if the time stamp has been at least or longer than 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (strtotime($timestamp) <= strtotime('-1 month'))
```

Answer (score 3):

First, create a `DateTime` object from your time string and one for now

```
$dt = new DateTime($timestamp);
$now = new DateTime;
```

Then, create some DateInterval objects

```
$oneMonth = new DateInterval('P1M');
$fiveMinutes = new DateInterval('PT5M');
```

Then, do your comparisons

```
if ($dt >= $now->sub($oneMonth)) {
}

if ($dt >= $now->sub($fiveMinutes)) {
}
```

Comment: I love the `DateTime` classes.  +1

Comment: @Talon You need PHP 5.3.0 or newer to use the `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes